# Zooming of graph of a function

Tags: java, math, graph, zooming, scaling

I'm trying to figure out a proper algorithm of zooming of graph of some function.
Let's assume we have simple parabola drawed on a square panel, for example, JPanel. And I can select square area with my mouse to zoom. The question is, how can I zoom exactly that area? Some just bitmap transformations don't suit me. I want, apparently, somehow analytically to calculate maybe some offsets and factors. Of course I have function of my parabola inside my program, inside the code.

Any ideas or advice?

Comment: Yes, you have to calculate offsets and factors. Do you have a concrete problem with anything in particular?

Comment: That's why I asked that question. I can't get how to calculate it.